# statistics for histogram of periodic data

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, complex-numbers

For a series of angle values in (-pi, pi) range, I make a histogram. Is there an effective way to calculate a mean and modal (post probable) value? Consider following examples:

```
import numpy as N, cmath
deg = N.pi/180.
d = N.array([-175., 170, 175, 179, -179])*deg
i = N.sum(N.exp(1j*d))
ave = cmath.phase(i)
i /= float(d.size)
stdev = -2. * N.log(N.sqrt(i.real**2 + i.imag**2))

print ave/deg, stdev/deg
```

Now, let's have a histogram:

```
counts, bins = N.histogram(data, N.linspace(-N.pi, N.pi, 360))
```

Is it possible to calculate mean, mode having counts and bins? For non-periodic data, calculation of a mean is straightforward:

```
ave = sum(counts*bins[:-1])
```

Calculations of a modal value requires more effort. Actually, I'm not sure my code below is correct: firstly, I identify bins which occur most frequently and then I calculate an arithmetic mean:

```
cmax = bins[N.argmax(counts)]
mode = N.mean(N.take(bins, N.nonzero(counts == cmax)[0]))
```

I have no idea, how to calculate standard deviation from such data, though. One obvious solution to all my problems (at least those described above) is to convert histogram data to a data series and then use it in calculations. This is not elegant, however, and inefficient.

Any hints will be very appreciated.

---

This is the partial solution I wrote.

```
import numpy as N, cmath
import scipy.stats as ST

d = [-175, 170.2, 175.57, 179, -179, 170.2, 175.57, 170.2]
deg = N.pi/180.
data = N.array(d)*deg

i = N.sum(N.exp(1j*data))
ave = cmath.phase(i)  # correct and exact mean for periodic data
wrong_ave = N.mean(d)

i /= float(data.size)
stdev = -2. * N.log(N.sqrt(i.real**2 + i.imag**2))
wrong_stdev = N.std(d)

bins = N.linspace(-N.pi, N.pi, 360)
counts, bins = N.histogram(data, bins, normed=False)
# consider it weighted vector addition
nz = N.nonzero(counts)[0]
weight = counts[nz]
i = N.sum(weight * N.exp(1j*bins[nz])/len(nz))
pave = cmath.phase(i)  # correct and approximated mean for periodic data
i /= sum(weight)/float(len(nz))
pstdev = -2. * N.log(N.sqrt(i.real**2 + i.imag**2))
print
print 'scipy: %12.3f (mean) %12.3f (stdev)' % (ST.circmean(data)/deg, \
                                               ST.circstd(data)/deg)
```

When run, it gives following results:

```
 mean:      175.840       85.843      175.360
stdev:        0.472      151.785        0.430

scipy:      175.840 (mean)        3.673 (stdev)
```

A few comments now: the first column gives mean/stdev calculated. As can be seen, the mean agrees well with scipy.stats.circmean (thanks JoeKington for pointing it out). Unfortunately stdev differs. I will look at it later. The second column gives completely wrong results (non-periodic mean/std from numpy obviously does not work here). The 3rd column gives sth I wanted to obtain from the histogram data (@JoeKington: my raw data won't fit memory of my computer.., @dmytro: thanks for your input: of course, bin size will influence result but in my application I don't have much choice, i.e. I have to reduce data somehow). As can be seen, the mean (3rd column) is properly calculated, stdev needs further attention :)

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to calculate data's mean, mode, std, etc from the histogram data? If so, it doesn't seem possible to me, because you loose a lot of information by taking the histogram of the data. All you can get is an approximation which gets worse with wider bins. Or is it what you're looking for?

Comment: Have a look at the Von Mises distribution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises_distribution .  If you want a book, Fisher's Statistical Analysis of Circular data is the standard textbook, and is usually fairly reasonably priced.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at `scipy.stats.circmean` and `scipy.stats.circstd`.

Or do you only have the histogram counts, and not the "raw" data?  If so, you could fit a [Von Mises distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises_distribution) to your histogram counts and approximate the mean and stddev in that way.

Comment: what if the data is far from being normally distributed?

Comment: @JoeKington: thanks for pointing out scipy.stats.{circmean,circstd}. The mean I calculated is exactly the same as circmean. I'll look into the code of circstd to find out why my results are different. I'm grateful also for bringing my attention to Von Mises distribution. The tip on fitting is also great. Actually before I come up with a partial solution (see edit) I independently hit on a similar idea and it works nicely..

Comment: @dmytro: you are right, the normal distribution is not a general solution, in my case I fitted p[0]*sin(a) exp(-0.5 (a/p[0])**2) with a good result. Thus fitting *a function* to the histogram data might be a solution in some cases.

Comment: @krzym - For `cricstd` (and `circmean`), be sure to specify the `high` and `low` kwargs properly. By default it assumes your data ranges from `0` to `2pi`.  If your data is in degrees or has a different range (e.g. `-pi` to `pi`), you'll need to specify a different `low` and `high`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get an approximation.

Since `Var(x) = <x^2> - <x>^2`, we have:

```
meanX = N.sum(counts * bins[:-1]) / N.sum(counts)
meanX2 = N.sum(counts * bins[:-1]**2) / N.sum(counts)
std = N.sqrt(meanX2 - meanX**2)
```

Comment: Those don't apply to circular data, for whatever it's worth. The mean is not simply the mean :)  (e.g. 359 degrees and 0 degrees are only 1 degree apart)

Comment: @JoeKington, fair enough. The author, however, mentioned non-periodic data and seem to be perfectly fine with his `sum(counts * bins[:-1])`, so I assumed the question is more about estimating moments from the histogram.

Comment: @dmytro: What I messed up in my original question was the way the mean for non-periodic data was calculated (my original histogram is normalized and this is why I neglected dividing by the sum of counts).  Actually in my code I need both cases: i.e. I need to handle periodic and non-periodic data, thus your solution for calculation of stdev is very much appreciated.