# Average day of the year across December-January

Tags: python, datetime, time-series, average, python-datetime

Imagine a time series that peaks cyclically around end-December/early-January. The maxima of the series will then have dates like those showed in `dt1` or `dt2` below. I need to compute the **average day of the year** (DOY) of those maxima.

The problem is that a normal average would give very different results for `dt1` (211) and  `dt2` (356). The cause is obviously that some elements of `dt1` are in January, so the corresponding DOYs are very small and bring the resulting average down.

I originally worked this around using another month as the origin to calculate the DOYs, but this created problems with other time series peaked around the new origin.

Is there a general, **all-year-round** solution to this problem?

```python
dt1 = [datetime(2000, 12, 15), datetime(2001, 12, 16), datetime(2002,12,20), datetime(2004,1,2) , datetime(2005,1,1)]
dt2 = [datetime(2000, 12, 15), datetime(2001, 12, 16), datetime(2002,12,20), datetime(2003,12,31), datetime(2004,12,30)]
doys1 = np.array([dt.timetuple().tm_yday for dt in dt1])
doys2 = np.array([dt.timetuple().tm_yday for dt in dt2])
print doys1.mean()
print doys2.mean()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of googling, I've found that what you're looking for is a way to calculate a [mean of circular quantities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_circular_quantities). Some more googling revealed that this is implemented in the [`scipy` library](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/index.html). I've found it thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10270087/3903832), however I've failed in my attempts to locate some proper documentation on the function itself and reverted to inspecting the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/morestats.py) in order to find out how it should be invoked.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> 
>>> dt1 = [datetime(2000, 12, 15), datetime(2001, 12, 16), datetime(2002,12,20), datetime(2004,1,2) , datetime(2005,1,1)]
>>> dt2 = [datetime(2000, 12, 15), datetime(2001, 12, 16), datetime(2002,12,20), datetime(2003,12,31), datetime(2004,12,30)]
>>> doys1 = np.array([dt.timetuple().tm_yday for dt in dt1])
>>> doys2 = np.array([dt.timetuple().tm_yday for dt in dt2])
>>>
>>> stats.circmean(doys1, high=365)
357.39332727199502
>>> stats.circmean(doys2, high=365)
356.79551148217894
```